# How to get boolean property with expression language?

Tags: java, el

If I have a class like this:

```
class Person {
  private int age;
  public int getAge() {
    return age;
  }
  public boolean isAdult() {
    return age > 19;
  }
}
```

I can get the `age` with EL like this:

```
${person.age}
```

But, I cannot figure out how to get the `isAdult()`. How can I get this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2945061/java-how-to-name-boolean-properties

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do it like

```
${person.adult}
```

It will invoke `isAdult()`

It works on [java bean specifications.](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/spec-136004.html)

Comment: Thanks! Is there any other getters? Can I get property from the method like `hasSomething()`?

Comment: No standard accessor doesn't have this pattern. this is generally convention to name a method , please see the java beans specs

Answer (score 1):

Doing `${person.adult}` should work, unless you are using a very old version of JSP, in which case you may need to change your method name to `getAdult()` or even `getIsAdult()`.

Essentially this same question was asked (and answered) here:  [getting boolean properties from objects in jsp el](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518354/getting-boolean-properties-from-objects-in-jsp-el)

Answer (score 0):

The JavaBean specification defines `isXXX` for boolean getters and `getXXX` for other getter, so it should be exactly the same syntax: `${person.adult}`.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 class Person {
  private int age;
  private boolean adult;
  public int getAge() {
    return age;
  }
  public void isAdult() {
    adult = (age > 19);
  }
}

${person.adult}
```